# How to display only the highest "score" according to the text content inside each div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to archive the below by using JavaScript (or with jQuery). Here is the HTML structure:

```html
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A<div id="score">96+</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">B<div id="score">99</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">C<div id="score">99</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">D<div id="score">96-</div></div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A<div id="score">86</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">B<div id="score">88</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">C<div id="score">90</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">D<div id="score">90+</div></div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A<div id="score">83-</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">B<div id="score">83+</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">C<div id="score">76</div></div>
  <div class="score-item">D<div id="score">78</div></div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript will do the modification, and the desired results will be `B 99` `C90` `A 83-` , which looks like:

```html
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">B<div id="score">99</div></div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">C<div id="score">90</div></div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A<div id="score">83-</div></div>
</div>
```

The rules are:

1. Ignore all non-number in `id="score"`, eg. + and -, and do the ranking.
2. Show one highest score item.
3. If two score items are the same in a set, show just one according to the `div` item sequence inside `<div class="score-set">`, ie. in the above example A > B > C > D.
4. When writing the result, write the original `div` item, including + or -.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+table+cell+value+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use a class, and filter on class

Comment: Rule 1: ignore `+`/`-`, example shows `A83-` - so it can't ignore it then, if there's two that are `83+` and `83-` which would it show as there's 2 "original div items"?

Comment: and where is your code that tries to sort these data?

Comment: @DenizKaradağ OPs comment that they had no clue where to start was edited out.  Now it looks like a demand for code rather than the original request for help.

Comment: @freedomn-m Can we use something like `var str = score.innerHTML; str = str.replace(???? , "");` to remove? But maybe it would be even simpler if not to ignore + and -, as long as it can filter only one result from the set.
yes, my original text says "I have no clue about it yet". I am not a javascript guy, know a little, cannot find the answer after some search, and seek some ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do this, it would be best to get each individual score-set and treat one after another.

For each score item, we need to first get the score and transform it ([Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) into a number with no digits (`.replace(\/D+/g, '')`)and memorize the score item html object.

```js
Number(scoreItem.querySelector('div').innerText.replace(/\D+/g, ''))
```

We can then sort the remaining ones in descending order and simply take the first one of the list. Can be done with [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
.sort(({ score: scoreA }, { score: scoreB }) => scoreB - scoreA)
```

Then finally we update the score set html.

```js
scoreSet.innerHTML = '';
scoreSet.appendChild(scoreItem);
```

```js
const scoreSets = document.getElementsByClassName('score-set');

for(const scoreSet of scoreSets){
  
  const [{ scoreItem }] = Array
    .from(scoreSet.getElementsByClassName('score-item'), scoreItem => ({
      scoreItem,
      // it would be better here to access the score using the id
      // but `score` is used multiple times which makes getting 
      // the score element unreliable
      score: Number(scoreItem.querySelector('div').innerText.replace(/\D+/g, ''))
    }))
    .sort(({ score: scoreA }, { score: scoreB }) => scoreB - scoreA)
    
  scoreSet.innerHTML = '';
  scoreSet.appendChild(scoreItem);
}
```

```html
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A
    <div id="score">96+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">B
    <div id="score">99</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">C
    <div id="score">99</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">D
    <div id="score">96-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A
    <div id="score">86</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">B
    <div id="score">88</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">C
    <div id="score">90</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">D
    <div id="score">90+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A
    <div id="score">83-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">B
    <div id="score">83+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">C
    <div id="score">76</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">D
    <div id="score">78</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great solution with the explanation! and thanks for the recommendation too! I changed to `id="sdata"` in the real usage and make it `scoreItem.querySelector("#sdata")`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be MUCH simplified

Note I changed the invalid ID to class="score"

If you cannot do that, then change `.querySelector(".score")` to `.querySelector("div")`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.score-set').forEach(scoreSet => {
   const scores = [...scoreSet.querySelectorAll(".score-item")];
   scores.sort((a,b) => parseInt(b.querySelector(".score").textContent) - parseInt(a.querySelector(".score").textContent))
   scoreSet.innerHTML ="";
   scoreSet.append(scores[0])
})
```

```html
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A
    <div class="score">96+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">B
    <div class="score">99</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">C
    <div class="score">99</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">D
    <div class="score">96-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A
    <div class="score">86</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">B
    <div class="score">88</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">C
    <div class="score">90</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">D
    <div class="score">90+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="score-set">
  <div class="score-item">A
    <div class="score">83-</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">B
    <div class="score">83+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">C
    <div class="score">76</div>
  </div>
  <div class="score-item">D
    <div class="score">78</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment:  ingenious solution. It's great to learn about [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Yeah, it works because your non-numerics are traiiling.